# suggestion for filtering data frame based on k class

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have two catogery column the values in first are client_abc, client_def,
the second column are F1,F2,F3 and rest are the numeric column.

data looks like

```
 date       client          facility     count     claim
21/3/2019   'client_abc'     F1           200        1300
22/3/2019    'client_def'    F2           400        1800
21/3/2019    'client_abc'    F3           1000       3000
22/3/2019    'client_def'    F1           380        3600
21/3/2019    'client_abc'    F2           900        900
22/3/2019    'client_def'    F3           1030       2500
21/3/2019    'client_abc'    F1           190        1700
22/3/2019    'client_def'    F2           100000     1560
```

for client 'abc' and 'f1'

```
 date       client          facility     count     claim
21/3/2019   'client_abc'     F1           200        1300
21/3/2019    'client_abc'    F1           190        1700
```

similarly for `'abc' and 'f2'` ,`'abc' and 'f3'`, `'def' and 'f1'`,`'def' and 'f2'`,`'def' and 'f3'`.

My attempt

```
df_fac_f1 =df[facility=='F1' & client == 'client_abc' ]
df_fac_f1 =df[facility=='F1' & client == 'client_def' ]
df_fac_f1 =df[facility=='F2' & client == 'client_abc' ]
df_fac_f1 =df[facility=='F2' & client == 'client_def' ]
df_fac_f1 =df[facility=='F3' & client == 'client_abc' ]
df_fac_f1 =df[facility=='F3' & client == 'client_def' ]
```

How ca I get the same result without knowing the `facility` and `client` column values in advance?

Comment: This is wrong for many reasons, starting by the fact that the bitwise operators have a higher precedence than comparissons, and obviously `'F1' & client` makes no sense.  You should be doing  `(df['facility']=='F1']) & (df['client'] == 'client_abc')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['client','facility'])
print(grouped.get_group(('client_abc', 'F1')))
```

output:

```
         date      client facility  count
 0  21/3/2019  client_abc       F1    200
 2  21/3/2019  client_abc       F1   1000
 4  21/3/2019  client_abc       F1    900
 6  21/3/2019  client_abc       F1    190
```

Comment: hai @Chirag .how do I get for all other  class without specifying eachtime

Comment: you can get all keys by print(grouped.groups.keys())

Answer (score 0):

```py
for group, grouped in df.groupby(["facility", "client"]):
    pass # grouped is a df of grouped by this columns values
```

[More info](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)